# Downgrade expression engine v3 to v2

Tags: ee2, ee3, plugin

Is it easy to downgrade from version 3.5 to 2.9? I have a client that do not like the interface and don't want to upgrade some plugin's too. And how must I downgrade

Greetings Marc

Comment: You'd need to restore your backup as jcogs.eecms says. This is not in the best interests of your client. Keeping web software up to date is important. 2.9 is almost three years old, and your client is missing critical performance and security fixes. 2.11.8 would be better, but should still be a launchpad to move them to the current version, since version 2 is retiring at the end of this month and will not receive any more fixes after that. Change can be hard, but give it time, they will grow to appreciate the improved UI.

Comment: Despite what Derek Jones says, I think this is a valid question, and certainly it is not a given that all users of EE2 should necessarily upgrade to EE3.  The migration, particularly where non-EE3 compatible add-ons are being used, is time consuming and can be expensive, and yields few functional gains.  The CP interface in EE3 is quite different from EE2, and can lead to UI problems that are less pressing in EE2 (e.g. wide Grid fields).  For many sites updating only to the latest EE2 version is a valid and prudent course; EllisLabs' decision to retire support for EE2 is short-sighted I think.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not a sensible path to downgrade from EE3 to EE2.

Probably better to simply reinstate a backup of your EE2 from before your upgrade to EE3 onto a local server and then patch over whatever changes in content have been made since you did the upgrade, and then put the EE2 version back online.

If you are still at the point where you are trying to work out how to get around add-ons that haven't been migrated to EE3, I suspect the amount of work involved in restoring the backup is not huge.

Good luck!